# How many MAX7219 8x8 can a Raspberry Pi 3 power?

Tags: pi-3, power, power-supply, led

I'm trying to figure out how many MAX7219 8x8 LED matrix can a Raspberry Pi 3 handle without the need of external power.

[image]

I would like to connect an array of 8 but I suspect I'll need an external power. What would be the estimated power consumption with all the 512 LED lights?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the 5 V pin, you can draw [as much current as your power supply allows](https://elinux.org/RPi_Low-level_peripherals#Power_pins), as stated on eLinux:

> Maximum permitted current draw from the 5 V pin is the USB input current (usually 1 A) minus any current draw from the rest of the board.

Note that for the Pi 3, the 1 A current input is inaccurate; the Pi Foundation [recommend 2.5 A](https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/faqs/#powerReqs) instead. [pinout.xyz](https://pinout.xyz/pinout/pin2_5v_power) suggest that "with a decent power supply, such as the official Pi adaptor, you can expect to pull about 1.5A."

The [MAX7219 datasheet](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/General/COM-09622-MAX7219-MAX7221.pdf) states that:

> **Operating Supply Current:** TYP 330 mA

So, with 8 LED matrices, you're looking at 330 mA * 8 = 2.64 A, which is probably beyond what your PSU can supply.

Also interesting: the [documentation](http://wayoda.github.io/LedControl/pages/hardware.html) for the LedControl Arduino library, which goes into detail about the hardware decisions you will face.  Note that the current draw will depend on the LEDs that you've chosen — as pointed out in the section 'Selecting RSet', if you have LEDs demanding only 20 mA, you'll only have a 170 mA typical draw.

Comment: The 330mA typ rating assumes 40mA per LED segment which is maximum brightness.  Each segment is cycled on 1/8 of the time but 40mA would still be more than you'd normally need.  The MAX7219 is a current source.  You put a voltage divider on the I(set) pin to determine brightness and therefore output current.  With a 20kOhm resistor it will be approx 168mA all up, with 40kOhm resistor it will be approx 88mA all up.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good research by user marco_c on Arduino forum where you can see that MAX7219 is not drawing that much power.

http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=301955.0

It probably depends on different versions/manufacturers of MAX7219 but his draw only 2.6mA with no LEDs turned on and 67mA with all LEDs at maximum brightness.
In that case you could easily power 8 pieces of 8x8 LED matrix with max consumption of 0.5A.

Comment: That's with an R(set) of 62kOhm, which is a lower brightness setting than all 3 brightness settings suggested in the MAX7219 datasheet.  But depending on your needs and type of LED, could well be as much as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, there's no reason why you couldn't power the LED array from a separate power supply. As long as the ground lines are connected there should be no problem and you can simply use a power supply with as much output as needed.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question; "I'm trying to figure out how many MAX7219 8x8 LED matrix can a Raspberry Pi 3 handle without the need of external power."!